# creating pkpass files for Apple Wallet/Passbook on server-side

Tags: ios, linux, server, wallet

I'm new to iOs development, I am android developer.

I followed the apple developer [instruction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1) and managed to create working boarding pass(pkpass file). But it's static and i built it using my macbook.

What i want is to generate somehow the pkpass file on server side and then open it from my iphone/ipad device.

Is this possible or not?

Here is the instruction to create pkpass [manually](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1)

It's using some commands like -openssl, -zip and also using apple dev certificates. I wonder if it can be done on server side and how to use on server side this certificates? Server side running php

Comment: Yes it is possible. In one of my app we are generating pkpass dynamically from server

Comment: Check https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass and http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/passbook-tutorial/

Comment: Hi, can anyone here guide me how it works it on the server-side, how I can call from ios side to server-side

Comment: Hi, just a quick question - In case of Insurance card use card - Ideally who should generate the .pkpass file - Backend or Mobile client?

Comment: There also seems to be a python package for this now - https://github.com/devartis/passbook